# Elementos mismo nombre diccionario Python

Tags: python, diccionarios

estoy contando mensajes repetidos que existen en lapsos de 30 días, luego de esto se vuelve a contar desde cero los mensajes. Por ejemplo, en 30 días hubo 5 mensajes tipo "A", después del último mensaje tipo "A" pasaron 30 días y no se reportó ningún tipo "A" nace una nueva historía del tipo "A".

Lo que me pasa es que estoy añadiendo todo a un diccionario y cuando un mensaje tipo "A" se vuelve a reportar luego de que no lo hacía hace un tiempo, el diccionario no me considera la historia anterior ya que lo reemplaza.

Quiero imprimir las cantidades de alertas de ambas historias pero resulta que tienen igual nombre. Me es muy difícil cambiar el nombre, ya que son miles de nombres y el nombre lo utilizo para buscar los repetidos.

Será posible tener un diccionario con elementos llamados igual, pero que en el fondo sean distintos.

Comment: Si con elementos iguales te refieres a claves iguales la respuesta es no. Un diccionario (y los conjuntos) se implementan mediante tablas hash lo que implica mucha eficiencia en búsquedas (entre otras cosas) pero implica que no mantienenel orden y que no pueden tener elementos o claves repetidas. Por lo que comentas lo suyo es usar Pandas agrupando por tiempo y por mensaje deberia ser una línea (dependiendo de como tengas organizados los datos). Si aportas algo más sobre la estructura de los datos es podible que podamos aportar ideas, con lo que tenemos poco podemos hacer. Saludos.

Comment: Hola, ¿se puede agrupar usando pandas por fecha?. Los datos son cadenas, que se repiten n veces, cada repetición arroja una fecha. La idea es ir contando los repetidos bajo y armando historias (una historia es una serie de repetidos, la cual se corta cuando después del último repetido pasan más de 30 días.

Comment: Por supuesto, por fecha o por cualquier cosa agrupable. Solo tienes que parsear adecuadamente las fechas (si son cadenas) para pasarlas a datetime creando una columna o index con ellas. Después puedes agrupar por tiempo (dias, horas, minutos, meses, años, por dias laborables/no laborables, por semanas, etc. Si quieres agrupar por meses naturales o de un dia del mes a otro dia del mes o simplemente cada 30 dias empezando desde el primero no es problema.

Comment: Solo para complementar el comentario de FJSevilla, puedes eventualmente crear claves compuestas en un diccionario del tipo "A1", "B2", etc según el ciclo que mencionabas, pero eso dependerá de tus necesidades.

Comment: @FJSevilla pero puedo agrupar por fechas, pero en mi caso estás agrupaciones son móvil, ya que necesito volver a agrupar lo mismo siempre y cuando la última cadena deje una holgura de 30 días en que vuelva a aparecer. Estoy trabajando con np.genfromtxt y estoy compliado con mi código :(